# Manipulating numbers obtained from a VBA search

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to craft a script in Word that will allow me to programmatically update times stored in a word document as minutes and seconds.  The times are written like this, `[01:10]` and I would like to find each number, and increment it by a specific, consistent number of minutes and seconds.

I am able to find the timecodes with the following code, but can't figure out how I can convert them into numbers that I can then manipulate and plug back into the document.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub findreplace()
Dim objWdDoc As Document
Set objWdDoc = ActiveDocument
Dim objWdRng As Range
Set objWdRng = objWdDoc.Content
With objWdRng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\[([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])\]"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    If .Execute Then
        Do While objWdRng.Find.Found = True
        .Text = "[0-9][0-9]"
        If .Execute Then
            'Do something here!!
        End If
        Loop
    End If
End With
Set objWdRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your regex?

Comment: `.Text = "\[([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])\]"`

Comment: `.Text` is a property that returns a string my friend.
According to MSDN it's a property that  returns or sets the text to find. Read/write String. What do you exactly want  to do in Simple English.

Comment: Convert a time stored in the format [01:23] ([mm:ss]) into seconds, add a specified number of seconds, convert it back into [mm:ss] and replace the string.

Comment: Please remove the regex tag from your question and correct your question title. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, here's a sub in which you supply the time and the seconds that you want to add and it will  `debug.print` the time in the `MM:SS` format.

```
Sub Main()
Dim T As Date 
T = #1:24:00 PM# ' <- Your time goes there 
Dim MyTime As String
Dim Seconds As Long: Seconds = 85 ' Seconds to add
MyTime = Format(DateAdd("s", Seconds, T), "mm:ss")
Debug.Print (MyTime)
End Sub
```

Example: Added 100 seconds to the date above, see the output below (*My French locale has a 24 hours format so don't mind that.*)

[image]

**Edit:** as per your comment, here's a function that you can call it from any sub.

```
Function AddSeconds(T As date, Seconds as Long) As String
Dim MyTime As String: MyTime = ""
MyTime = Format(DateAdd("s", Seconds, T), "mm:ss")
AddSeconds = MyTime
End Sub
```

Please:

1. Be aware that when you call the function, you need to supplement the
   correct argument format of a time like the following example:

   *MyNewTime = AddSeconds(#3:25:15 AM#,15)*
2. It will return a string datatype and **not a Date** so `MyNewTime` must be a string or a variant.

Comment: This works for one time, but how would I make it work for every time found in the document?  Will it work as described on each .Text?

Comment: Let me convert to a function.